# Perl Net::SMTP - How to use

Tags: perl, smtp

Okay, I just spent the last four hours trying to figure out why my implementation of Net::SMTP module was no longer working.

In short, I was doing this (removing error checking stuff for clarity):

```
 my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(Host => $host);
 $smtp->send($from);
 $smtp->data;
 $smtp->datasend($message);
 $smtp->dataend;
 $smtp->quit;
```

This had worked before, but now I was getting:

```
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7f9893114798)>>> SEND FROM:<from@address.com>
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x7f9893114798)<<< 450 Unable to send to "<from@address.com" at this time
```

This was from my `send` method.

The Perldoc wasn't too much of a help because the `send`, `send_and_mail`, `send_or_mail`, and `mail` commands are all described together, and I had assumed were pretty much aliases of each other.

I looked at other examples and decided to  try `$smtp->mail` and not `$smtp->send` That worked.

So, what are the differences between the `send`, `mail`, `send_and_mail`, and `send_or_mail` methods?. Do I need to try each one? I know they correspond to the `MAIL`, `SEND`, `SOML` and `SAML` commands in SMTP, but I can't really find anything that tells me what the differences are. And, do different SMTP servers use different commands. (Maybe that's why the `send` method previously worked?)

Comment: Good explanation of the differences between MAIL, SEND, SOML, and SAML:  http://cr.yp.to/smtp/send.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SMTP) docs mention that you're supposed to be familiar with the SMTP protocol.  That's currently specified by [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). [Appendix F.6 of RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#appendix-F.6) discusses the now-obsolete SEND command.  (It was supposed to deliver a message directly to the terminal, but that was rarely implemented.  Some servers may have interpreted it as a synonym for MAIL.)

The short version is that you should be using the MAIL command.  Or, even better, a higher-level module like [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the appendix. Now, I know what these commands do.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 5321, appendix F.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#appendix-F.6):

> "In addition to specifying a mechanism for delivering messages to
> user's mailboxes, RFC 821 provided additional, optional, commands to
> deliver messages directly to the user's terminal screen.  These
> commands (SEND, SAML, SOML) were rarely implemented, and changes in
> workstation technology and the introduction of other protocols may
> have rendered them obsolete even where they are implemented.

> "Clients SHOULD NOT provide SEND, SAML, or SOML as services.  Servers
> MAY implement them.  If they are implemented by servers, the
> implementation model specified in RFC 821 MUST be used and the
> command names MUST be published in the response to the EHLO command."

Comment: Yay, history! I guess OP wants to use $smtp->mail($from); since about 15 years :)

Comment: I've previously talked to Solaris machines for SMTP, and I guess they had `SEND` as more or less an alias to the `MAIL` command. Now, that I saw the appendix, I know what the differences between these four commands. I can now see why `send` is obsolete.